# How to find the first value of Bollinger Bands when bar open

Tags: charts, pine-script, indicator, pine-script-v4

Actually, the Bollinger Bands code is:

```
//@version=4
study(title="AAAA", shorttitle="AAAA", overlay=true)

len = 5
multi = 2

bb5med = sma(close, len)
devBB5 =  mult2 * stdev(close, len)
bb5top =  bb5med + devBB5
bb5bot =  bb5med - devBB5
```

I would want to find the first value of those 3 lines when the new bar comes, means, when close==open.

Also, I need it to work when I change the len to 20, 50 and/or when I change the multi to 3

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("BB Open", overlay = true)

len = input.int(20)
mult = input.float(2.000)

basis = (math.sum(close, len - 1)[1] + open) / len

float dev_sum = 0.0

for i = 1 to len - 1
    dev_sum += math.pow(basis - close[i], 2)

dev_sum += math.pow(basis - open, 2)

stdev = math.sqrt(dev_sum / len)

up = basis + stdev * mult
dn = basis - stdev * mult

plot(basis, color = color.yellow)
plot(up)
plot(dn)
```

Function :

```
f_BBopen(_close, _open, _len, _mult) =>
    _basis = (math.sum(_close, _len - 1)[1] + _open) / _len

    float _dev_sum = 0.0

    for i = 1 to _len - 1
        _dev_sum += math.pow(_basis - _close[i], 2)

    _dev_sum += math.pow(_basis - _open, 2)

    _stdev = math.sqrt(_dev_sum / _len)

    _up = _basis + _stdev * _mult
    _dn = _basis - _stdev * _mult
    [_basis, _up, _dn]

[basis, up, dn] = f_BBopen(close, open, len, mult)
```

Comment: Please make it as a function

Comment: Can you please help me with another lines: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991487/how-to-find-the-first-value-when-bar-open-of-ema-sma)