# How to find the first value when bar open of ema, sma

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have the plots:

```
E = ema(close, 34)

S = sma(close, 14)
```

I would like to get the value of the 2 above lines when the first close == open (means when the bar appears, at the first second of the timeframe).

How can I do that. Please help me to write 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

On historical bars, scripts execute on the close, so no values from the beginning of the bar are available, other than `open`. You could always use the values calculated on the last bar's close with `E[1]` for example, but that would not necessarily be equivalent to a value obtained at the open of the bar, when a new bar opens at a different price than the previous bar's close, and also because of the fact that you would not be using the same 34 or 14 values to calculate your MAs.

On realtime bars, you could achieve what you want using the [`varip`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#varip) variables introduced in Pine Script™ v5:

```
//@version=5
indicator("", "", true)
E = ta.ema(close, 34)
S = ta.sma(close, 14)

varip float eAtOpen = na
varip float sAtOpen = na
if barstate.isrealtime and barstate.isnew
    eAtOpen := E
    sAtOpen := S
plot(eAtOpen, "eAtOpen")
plot(sAtOpen, "sAtOpen", color.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, someone can find the first value of another line: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612000/how-to-find-the-first-value-of-bollinger-bands-when-bar-open/71613409#71613409)

Comment: Yes it does, but it doesn't change the fact that the calculation is only available at the close of historical bars because that's when they are calculated. In realtime it would work similarly to the above example's code. It is no doubt an ingenious method of handling the problem, but it requires custom-coding each function, so `ta.ema()` and `ta.sma()` in the op's case.